# Samba share for Windows 7 machines with hostname

Tags: samba, sles

I have a samba share and this should only be accessible by some machines. So, I tried to set the "hosts allow"-parameter in my share. This is working fine for IP addresses, but we have dynamic addresses, so I want to use the Win7 machine names. But as soon as I switch the current IPs to the hostnames, the users get a password prompt in Windows. There is no hosts allow specified in [global] section. I set the var hostname lookups = yes, too. You can ping the hostname from the samba server. I have no idea why it isn't working with the SuSe machine.

What kind of parameter is missing? Has somebody other the same problem?

Logs just telling: [2017/03/14 23:54:37.573960, 0] lib/access.c:338(allow_access) Denied connection from (my.local.ip)

I tried a lot of things, but now I am really frustrated.

Regards, Wyphorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is:
define the hostname lookups = yes in the [global] section like the specification says and not in the share.
On my ubuntu server it works also when I define the lookup in the share directly. That was my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I faced the literally same issues some time ago, and this article was really helpful https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2078120&page=3 
Also, when it comes to switching from IPs to Names it always comes with troubles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think the related link goes in another direction. There is the problem, that on the client, he has to use the IP address of the host to access the share.
That's not what my problem is. My DNS is working well and I can reach the server with its hostname. I can access all public shares with \\servername\share. But this one new share which is restricted with "Hosts allow" won't work for computer names. If I use the IP address of the clients, all will be fine. But their hostnames won't work.